# Find method - multiple searches running simultaneously

Tags: cefsharp

How do I find multiple searches running simultaneously using the Find method within a certain webpage? For instance I want to find the words, "Tammy" AND "Family" on the same webpage using the Find method? The documentation reads that you can use the "identifier" parameter, but I've tried the following and it only finds the last "Find"...

browser.Find(1, "Tammy", True, False, False)
browser.Find(2, "Family", True, False, False)

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unlikely this scenario is supported. Can you run simultaneous searches in Chrome? You'd probably have to implement this in JavaScript.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, but it's in the documentation, so I am hopeful...

http://cefsharp.github.io/api/67.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_Find_1.htm

Comment: The documentation is version specific,  the link you've provided is for version 67. Version 86 is the current http://cefsharp.github.io/api/86.0.x/html/M_CefSharp_IBrowserHost_Find.htm